# Incorrect result with mysql date comparison

Tags: mysql, database

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM items 
WHERE status='public' 
AND DATE(dateCreated) >= '01-01-2012' 
AND DATE(dateCreated) <= '31-12-2012'
```

To get a count of all the items added in 2012.  Result: 629

However if I change the year to 2011, I get the exact same result.

If I remove the date comparison completely, and just do:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS num
FROM items
WHERE STATUS =  'public'
```

That also gives 629 rows as the result, even though there are items added all the way from 2009-2012 in the table, and each year should give a different count.

What am I doing wrong?

The dateCreated column is a datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is declared as datetime, you can just compare dates using the yyyy-MM-dd format for dates or yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss for datetimes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM items 
WHERE status='public' 
AND dateCreated >= '2012-01-01' 
AND dateCreated <= '2012-12-31'
```

If you use the DATE() function and compare against a date in your format, you are actually comparing strings alphabetically, so with format dd-mm-yyyy any date would start with a digit between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM items 
WHERE status='public' 
AND dateCreated >= '2012-01-01' 
AND dateCreated <= '2012-12-31'
```

From the MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format